# SQL server merge Delete with filter

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

Im using merge to do an insert or delete, and im not sure how that is supposed to look. I have a mapping table that maps a taxonomy to a supported language. That table looks like:

```
TaxonomyLanguageID(PK) | TaxonomyID(FK) | LanguageID(FK)
```

What i want to do is merge a temp table with the table above, where the temp table will have a list of a Taxonomies supported languages. For example:

```
TaxonomyID|LanguageID

456,        2

456,        3

456,        9
```

What i've tried looks like this (The select is for testing, later this will be a temp table):

```
MERGE dbo.TaxonomyLanguages as t
using (SELECT 5395  as TaxonomyID, 2 as LanguageID) as s
ON (s.TaxonomyID=T.TaxonomyID AND s.LanguageID=t.LanguageID)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT(TaxonomyID,LanguageID) VALUES(S.TaxonomyID,s.LanguageID)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND T.TaxonomyID=s.TaxonomyID
    THEN DELETE;
```

What i want this to do is insert if it doesn't match, and delete if it doesn't, but only delete those rows in the target where it matches the taxonomyID found in the source.

But i get a "Only target columns are allowed in the 'when not matched by source' clause" error.

Any idea on how to work around this (or how its supposed to be done)?

Example of what im looking for. If i have a source Like

```
TaxonomyID|LanguageID

4000,      2

4000,      3
```

And a target like:

```
TaxonomyLanguageID|TaxonomyID|LanguageID

1,                  3000       2

2,                  4000       1

3,                  4000       2
```

The end result would be:

```
TaxonomyLanguageID|TaxonomyID|LanguageID

1,                 3000       2

3,                 4000       2

4,                 4000       3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to break it into two passes because the number of key fields are different.

```
Select 456 as TaxonomyID, 2 as LanguageID
  into TaxonomyLanguages

INSERT INTO [dbo].[TaxonomyLanguages]
           ([TaxonomyID]
           ,[LanguageID])
     VALUES
           (456, 3)
           ,(456, 9)
GO

select *
from [TaxonomyLanguages]


MERGE dbo.TaxonomyLanguages as t
using (SELECT 5395  as TaxonomyID, 2 as LanguageID) as s
ON (s.TaxonomyID=T.TaxonomyID AND s.LanguageID=t.LanguageID)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT(TaxonomyID,LanguageID) VALUES(S.TaxonomyID,s.LanguageID);


MERGE dbo.TaxonomyLanguages as t
using (SELECT 5395  as TaxonomyID, 2 as LanguageID) as s
ON (s.TaxonomyID=T.TaxonomyID)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE 
    THEN DELETE;

select *
from [TaxonomyLanguages]
```

Based on comment, change second merge:

```
MERGE dbo.TaxonomyLanguages as t
using (SELECT 456  as TaxonomyID, 3 as LanguageID) as s
ON (s.TaxonomyID=T.TaxonomyID)
WHEN  MATCHED 
  and (s.LanguageID <> T.LanguageID)
    THEN DELETE;
```

Comment: I may have made my question poorly, but this just deletes all other rows. I only want to delete rows that match the TaxonomyID in source, but dont match the languageID. Ill update my question with an example

Comment: OK. Then use MATCHED with a filter.

Comment: MERGE dbo.TaxonomyLanguages as t
using (SELECT 456  as TaxonomyID, 3 as LanguageID) as s
ON (s.TaxonomyID=T.TaxonomyID)
WHEN  MATCHED 
  and (s.LanguageID <> T.LanguageID)
    THEN DELETE;